# Android tutorials for OpenGL with API level 10

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am currently trying to learn how to use OpenGLes in Android, but all of the tutorials I have found do not use API level 10. (i.e. Gingerbread/2.3)

EDIT: Well, at least they say they use it, but when I build it gives me errors as if it isn't there...

They require `EGLConfig` in setting the renderer and surface. Example:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)...
```

Taken from [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html).

Would anyone know a solution to this, or a reference to a tutorial that does this?

Comment: AFAIK EGLConfig has been there since Level 1, no?

Comment: It has! That's why I've come here. I've been at it for several hours, and I've gone through the Reference several times. I even copy/pasted the tutorial, and still nothing.

Comment: Imports fine for me in a 2.2-4.1 project.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or command-line?

Comment: This one was in Eclipse and Intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK EGLConfig has been there since Level 1, no? That's a *really* old tutorial, though.

Maybe something more recent like [this one](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/?)?